# DIV with background pattern & transparent bottom arrow. How to?

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, svg

Background of html tag with pattern, block with bottom transparent arrow is with pattern too. How to make the arrow transparent, so that the background block was seen underneath?

When browser window change width, background of the block moves.

ScreenShot:
http://s48.radikal.ru/i119/1407/b5/02578fecc1ff.gif

**P.S**. `div` with arrow will be with other blocks inside

Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

if you use Cal() which only work in i.e. 9 and up this will be my solution. 
create two trapezoid, instead of masking the triangle.

http://jsfiddle.net/JrfyN/

HTML

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="arrow">
    <div class="trapezoid left"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid right"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS

```
#top{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:lightgrey;
    position:relative;
}
#arrow {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#bottom {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background:grey;
}
.trapezoid {
    width: calc(50% - 50px); 
    border-bottom: 50px solid grey;
    height: 0;
    display:block;
}
.left {float:left; border-right: 50px solid transparent;}
.right {float:right; border-left: 50px solid transparent;}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JrfyN/2/ i thought this match your sreen shot.  do you plan on using a pattern for the bottom part too? if you only need pattern for the top, this will work? can you specify?

Comment: Maybe the screen shot is not good quality, there is background pattern where you placed white.

But if i don`t find better solution, i will use your with little trick.

Comment: wow thanks, I learned something too, I am usually frustrated with svg hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

You may use linear-gradient as a mask if it is a plain color:

CSS for instance with an arrow 50px height. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eiJwf)**

```
 background:
    linear-gradient(to right,white,white) no-repeat bottom  right,
    linear-gradient(to right,white,white) no-repeat bottom left,
    linear-gradient(  225deg,  transparent 60.2%, white 60%) bottom center no-repeat ,  
    linear-gradient( -225deg,  transparent 60.2%, white 60%) bottom center  no-repeat ,   
    linear-gradient(to left,purple,lime)/* last is your pattern */;
  background-size:45% 50px, 45% 50px, 200px 50px, 200px 50px, 100% 100%;
;
```

You can add a `padding-bottom`, of minimum arrow's height,  to element to avoid content to be seen on that arrow area.

No need here of extra markup or pseudo elements to draw it.

**[DEMO with a background repeated image](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abksF)**

---

You may overlap two differents texture using extra markup : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zeodD)**

---

Comment: Thnx, but it`s not really what i need.
I find solution jsbin.com/poneciro/1/edit

Comment: @user2883821 oki, svg mask is a good way. there was this with extra markup to be closer to your needs : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zeodD (demo using too different abstract backgrounds.